# Precedence on System Administration questions?

Tags: discussion, migration, scope

Do we have a precedence on questions that are based more on servers than unix? P.S. I'm specifically thinking that I might want to migrate [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37937/29) to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: If you haven't seen it already you should see this post.  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/  It covers this topic at a broad level.

Answer (score 6):

All unix questions are on-topic here, except programming questions (which we redirect to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)).

Some unix questions are also on-topic elsewhere ([Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) are the usual suspects). When it comes to questions that are on-topic on multiple sites, the general policy is that **they stay where they were asked**.

Sometimes a question might be migrated: if it's a far better match for another site and only borderline where it was asked; or if it goes un(satisfactorily)-answered for a while. If the question works where it's posted, it should not be migrated.

Case in point: [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37937/email-sent-from-web-server-using-php-does-not-arrive) has an accepted answer. It's not a significantly better fit for SF than for U&L. Don't migrate it.

Comment: note: wasn't accepted when I posted. I personally would have thought that one is a significantly better fit personally, since none of it has anything at all to do with unix. In fact all the steps mentioned apply to php/mailservers on windows.

Comment: @xenoterracide [Offtopic - A Stance - Programming / Servers / Cross Platform Applications](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/97)

Comment: but if you think that it's a good enough fit, you do way more for this site than I do

Comment: lol basically referencing things I wrote, that's epic. eh, whatever.